# How do I optimise this repeating var code?

Tags: javascript, php

How do I make it optimised? It doesn't really work with while for me. I need these rows of code to be in less rows.

```
var a[0]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[0]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var a[1]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[1]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var a[2]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[2]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var a[3]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[3]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var a[4]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[4]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var a[5]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[5]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var a[6]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[6]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[0]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[0]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[1]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[1]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[2]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[2]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[3]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[3]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[4]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[4]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[5]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[5]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
    var b[6]="<?php echo print_r($tempb[6]["descr"], true);
    ?>";
```

Comment: Do the `tempa` and `tempb` arrays have 6 items in them?

Comment: I think that you should not mix JS and PHP using this approach. Why you not make an API?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes

Comment: @CertainPerformance 7

Comment: Just write it to an array.....

Comment: You can also generate JSON and parse it in JS. Creating vars like this is wrong - you should create an array or object and then add/push elements to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have:

```php
<?php 
    $tempa = [
        ["descr" => "A0"],
        ["descr" => "A1"],
        ["descr" => "A2"],
        ["descr" => "A3"],
        ["descr" => "A4"],
        ["descr" => "A5"],
        ["descr" => "A6"],
    ];

    $tempb = [
        ["descr" => "B0"],
        ["descr" => "B1"],
        ["descr" => "B2"],
        ["descr" => "B3"],
        ["descr" => "B4"],
        ["descr" => "B5"],
        ["descr" => "B6"],
    ];
?>
```

all you need in JavaScript is:

```js
const a = <?= json_encode(array_column($tempa, "descr")) ?>;
const b = <?= json_encode(array_column($tempb, "descr")) ?>;
console.log(a); //  ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"]
console.log(b); //  ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"]
```

by using PHP's [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Or if you like ES6 syntax:

```js
const [a, b] = <?= json_encode([
  array_column($tempa, "descr"),
  array_column($tempb, "descr"),
]) ?>;
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot, now I finally know how to correctly use my arrays from api

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach` to loop over each variable, and output the JavaScript code for that variable index.

You can't declare individual array elements with `var`. Instead, use `json_encode()` to generate the entire array.

```
var a = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($tempa, "descr")); ?>;
var b = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($tempb, "descr")); ?>;
```

Comment: Seems like you copied over some bad code. var should not be there.... `var a[0] = 123;`

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, I came up with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++):?>
   var a[<?=$i?>]="<?php echo print_r($tempa[$i]["descr"], true);
?>";
<?php endfor;?>
```

Comment: I don't personally 100% like the way the code is written, but this answer seems to me to be the better one. I am not sure that it will work without modifications, but its on the right way. I don't understand the vote against it.

Comment: `var a[0] = 123;`